# Weird and Unasked Background Activities in Ubuntu Studio 19.10

Tags: cpu-load, ubuntu-studio, task-management

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10 inside two desktop PCs, both with the same machine configuration.

But, just in one of them, there are some annoying, weird and unasked activities, related with "**kworker**", "**gzip**", "**systemd**", "**sed**", "**md5sum**", "**cat**" and "**grep**", activities that eat a lot of CPU %, enough to freeze mouse movements, audio/video playing, etc. for 2 or more seconds, repeatedly during the time all those activities are working, more than one, two or three hours, each day at 12:00 o'clock (midday) and 00:00 o'clock (midnight).

There are not messages. There are not warning flashes. There is not some visible GUI... Just all those "behind the scene" activities.

I read something about, sometimes, this happens when we have a little amount of free HD space (which, in fact, is my case), but... In that article there is not some easy solution to avoid this.

Also, I found a "temporary" stupid solution... In a Terminal Session, with sudo privileges, I have been using the command "**killall**" to stop de "**cat**" service. But... Who is using "**cat**" without my permission? ???

Whatever... What's wrong here? How can I fix this? How can I avoid all those invisible activities?

It is really annoying to have to wait more than one or two hours up all those weird activities stop to work (if there was some end)!

This is an screen capture of the Task Monitor, showing the 100% CPU using of all those undesireable unvisible activities:

[image]

UPDATE!

I found that this is the task which is bother me:

[image]

I didn't schedule this! How can I avoid this task starts to run, again?

Please, some help!

Comment: Do you have automatic backups enabled? https://imgur.com/9j0OXUj

Comment: There is indeed an easy solution: Free up more HD space.

Comment: No, Organic Marble, I don't have any kind of automatic backup schedule. Even more, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: User535733, I cannot to buy a new HDD for the moment.. But... If the problem is the free space... Why the system does this without my direct permission? Isn't supposed that this is a machine and the user has to have the full control of all the actions? Why the system does something without to ask a clear authorization of the user? Is there a way to avoid this kind of behaviour?

Comment: so what is tiger and what is it doing? it looks like its making the calls to sed, and checksuming. Are you torrenting? Did you delete or move the torrent before its checksum completed? post a link to the source of tiger I want to see what nonsense theyve done. Or are you running the intrusion detection system tiger?

Comment: Hi, j0h! "Tiger" is inside the standard "Forensic-extras" utilities (Intrusion Detection System Tiger). But... I uninstall all that package and... It's still the same!!! "Grep", "Cat", "Kworker" and other activities are still present here, without any kind of control from me! I don't know what to do!!! Oh, I forget to say I don't have anything related with "Torrent" (even more, I don't have any clue about that)